# how to see P and BR tags in tinymce?

Tags: tags, tinymce, html, editor

As a developer, I'd really like to have the ability to see every tag written out on the editor in source mode. Is there a way? Some filter, action, or so?

Answer (score 0):

Easy thing, install plugin called [tinymce-advanced](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tinymce-advanced/) and in the setting page for the plugin just click check box for `Stop removing the p and br tags when saving and show them in HTML editor` and save.